# modelling the standard deviation as a function of x?

Tags: r, regression, standard-deviation

This may be very simple. Consider the following figure, minus the robot. How can I model the standard deviation of Speed as a function of Rep  [image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stats/img/captcha.png]

I can chop the rep up into arbitrary pieces (e.g. 2000 Rep's), calculate the sd, and then draw a regression line between de standard deviations, I also thought about moving window but that doesn't seem right. Is there a better, more continuous way, irrespective of arbitrary binning, to model standard deviation as a function of x?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious what is going on - variability is increasing with rep.  It's your job to quantify this, and both your suggestions are appropriate. Arbitrary binning will work; in this case the more the N's in each bin are similar the better. A sliding window might be better yet, but you're likely to see very similar trends.

Side note: keep in mind that sd often scales with the mean, which is why coefficient of variation is a popular metric.

Comment: What if the data is more sparse than in the picture. Isn't there a linear regression kind of way to model the sd so that it will take all points into account, not just those in the arbitrary choice of bins or windows ?

Comment: Sure, any [GLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) using a conditional distribution $y|x$ where the variance $\sigma_{y|x}^2$ depends on the mean $\langle{y|x}\rangle$ will do this. For example lognormal distribution, equivalent to doing standard linear regression on $\log[y]$ vs. $x$. You can *first* do some binning (or 2D [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)) to get an idea of what distribution may be appropriate.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you may also consider logging the predictor $x$, for either regression or binning/KDE. (From the looks of the plot, this would help to make the distribution more uniform, i.e. a uniform $\log[x]$ grid may have more similar $N$'s in each bin.)

Comment: Thanks, this sounds exactly what I was looking for. May I ask how a GLM model with a variance that depends on the mean would look like in R?
 In my data, I expect that the Standard deviation will be related to Rep in an exponential manner (sd ~ rep + rep^2 ), it would be great if I could estimate  the coefficients of rep and rep^2. The relationship of Mean~rep will be  0  as  I calculated residuals earlier

Comment: You would need to estimate the standard deviation and the mean together in general (and certainly for GLM). If your error variance changes with $x$, but you estimate the mean $\langle{y}\mid{x}\rangle$ ignoring this, then your baseline regression curve will be biased.

Comment: could you provide a glm model in R to do this considering the following data points? `x <- runif(1000) ` ;
`y <- 1 - 2*x + x*rnorm(1000)`
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a textbook case of heteroscedasticity for which the quantile regression might work well. The predicted lines for, say, 0.05 and 0.95 would trace out the upper and lower part of the distribution quite well, I would guess.